# Determining Functionality of Individual and Simultaneous keyPressed Events

Tags: input, keyboard, processing, simultaneous

EDIT #1:

After some playing around, I have a few different tests:

1. Write conditions which specify that the key is not coded (alphanumeric key presses do not register or function)

```py
float x = 50;
float y = 50;
float x2 = 40;
float y2 = 40;
void setup() {
  size(100, 100);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  rect(x, y, 10, 10);
  rect(x2, y2, 10, 10);
}

void keyPressed() {
  if (keyPressed) {
    if (key == CODED) {
      if (keyCode == LEFT) {
        x = x - 10;
        println("LEFT KEY PRESS; Square #1 moves LEFT", x);
      } else if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
        x = x + 10;
        println("RIGHT KEY PRESS; Square #1 moves RIGHT", x);
      } else if (keyCode == UP) {
        y = y - 10;
        println("UP KEY PRESS; Square #1 moves UP", y);
      } else if (keyCode == DOWN) {
        y = y + 10;
        println("DOWN KEY PRESS; Square #1 moves DOWN", y);
      } else if (key != CODED && key == 'a') {
        x2 = x2 - 10;
        println("'a' KEY PRESS; Square #2 moves LEFT", x2);
      } else if (key != CODED && key == 'd') {
        x2 = x2 + 10;
        println("'d' KEY PRESS; Square #2 moves RIGHT", x2);
      } else if (key != CODED && key == 'w') {
        y2 = y2 - 10;
        println("'w' KEY PRESS; Square #2 moves UP", y2);
      } else if (key != CODED && key == 's') {
        y2 = y2 + 10;
        println("'s' KEY PRESS; Square #2 moves DOWN", y2);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2. Start a separate conditional chain for alphanumeric keyPressed checks (alphanumeric key presses do not register or function)

```py
float x = 50;
float y = 50;
float x2 = 40;
float y2 = 40;
void setup() {
  size(100, 100);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  rect(x, y, 10, 10);
  rect(x2, y2, 10, 10);
}
void keyPressed() {
  if (keyPressed) {
    if (key == CODED) {
      if (keyCode == LEFT) {
        x = x - 10;
        println("LEFT KEY PRESS; Square #1 moves LEFT", x);
      } else if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
        x = x + 10;
        println("RIGHT KEY PRESS; Square #1 moves RIGHT", x);
      } else if (keyCode == UP) {
        y = y - 10;
        println("UP KEY PRESS; Square #1 moves UP", y);
      } else if (keyCode == DOWN) {
        y = y + 10;
        println("DOWN KEY PRESS; Square #1 moves DOWN", y);

        if (keyPressed) {
          if (key == 'a') {
            x2 = x2 - 10;
            println("'a' KEY PRESS; Square #2 moves LEFT", x2);
          } else if (key == 'd') {
            x2 = x2 + 10;
            println("'d' KEY PRESS; Square #2 moves RIGHT", x2);
          } else if (key == 'w') {
            y2 = y2 - 10;
            println("'w' KEY PRESS; Square #2 moves UP", y2);
          } else if (key == 's') {
            y2 = y2 + 10;
            println("'s' KEY PRESS; Square #2 moves DOWN", y2);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

3. Check for alphanumeric keys before checking for coded keys within a nested chain (seems to register all key presses and print correct results to console, and registers at least two simultaneous key presses, but the program will only continue to function as intended for the first key press when both are held)

```py
float x = 50;
float y = 50;
float x2 = 40;
float y2 = 40;
void setup() {
  size(100, 100);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  rect(x, y, 10, 10);
  rect(x2, y2, 10, 10);
}

void keyPressed() {
  if (keyPressed) {
    if (key == 'a') {
      x2 = x2 - 10;
      println("'a' KEY PRESS; Square #2 moves LEFT", x2);
    } else if (key == 'd') {
      x2 = x2 + 10;
      println("'d' KEY PRESS; Square #2 moves RIGHT", x2);
    } else if (key == 'w') {
      y2 = y2 - 10;
      println("'w' KEY PRESS; Square #2 moves UP", y2);
    } else if (key == 's') {
      y2 = y2 + 10;
      println("'s' KEY PRESS; Square #2 moves DOWN", y2);
    } else if (key == CODED) {
      if (keyCode == LEFT) {
        x = x - 10;
        println("LEFT KEY PRESS; Square #1 moves LEFT", x);
      } else if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
        x = x + 10;
        println("RIGHT KEY PRESS; Square #1 moves RIGHT", x);
      } else if (keyCode == UP) {
        y = y - 10;
        println("UP KEY PRESS; Square #1 moves UP", y);
      } else if (keyCode == DOWN) {
        y = y + 10;
        println("DOWN KEY PRESS; Square #1 moves DOWN", y);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

While I don't foresee any continuation of the original problem, the issue has shifted a bit to encompass simultaneous, continued keyPressed checks.

For the third test case, results are similar for combinations of alphanumeric-only, alphanumeric and coded, and coded-only key presses; movement starts, but is only continued for whichever key was pressed first.

To my knowledge, there is not a `keyHeld` option. There is a `keyReleased` option, but my guess is that this is not the solution here. I have tried to use `&&` to check for two keys, but this doesn't seem to work for alphanumeric keys (provides the error "The operator && is undefined for the argument type(s) char, char").

---

---

---

Original Post:
I'm working on replicating PONG right now and I'm having trouble getting both paddles to work. I wrote the following code into the existing program to modify the Y position of each paddle and added `println()` statements to see what was happening:

```
...

void keyPressed(){
  if (keyPressed){
    if (key == CODED){
      if (keyCode == UP){
        paddle_Y = paddle_Y - 20;
        println("UP");
      } else if (keyCode == DOWN){
        paddle_Y = paddle_Y + 20;
        println("DOWN");
      }
  if (keyPressed){
    if (key == 'w'){
      paddle_Y2 = paddle_Y2 - 20;
      println(key);
    } else if (key == 's'){
      paddle_Y2 = paddle_Y2 + 20;
      println(key);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  println(paddle_Y, paddle_Y2);
}
```

For this segment, `println("UP");`, `println("DOWN");`, and `println(paddle_Y, paddle_Y2);` are functioning as expected, with the console displaying results like this:

```
UP
480, 500
DOWN
500, 500
DOWN
520, 500
UP
500, 500
**'s' is pressed but does not print**
500, 500
**'w' is pressed but does not print**
500, 500
...
```

The current functionality is such that one paddle moves while the other does not. In another attempt to isolate the issue, I tried this instead as a separate program:

```
float x = 100;
float x2 = 100;

void setup(){
size(200, 200);
}

void keyPressed(){

  if (keyPressed){
    if (key == CODED){
      if (keyCode == UP){
        x = x - 20;
        println("UP");
      } else if (keyCode == DOWN){
        x = x + 20;
        println("DOWN");
      }
  if (keyPressed){
    if (key == 'w'){
      x2 = x2 - 20;
      println(key);
    } else if (key == 's'){
      x2 = x2 + 20;
      println(key);
        }
      }
    }
  }
   println(x, x2);
}
```

And in this program, nothing registers at all and no lines are printed to the console.

I'm lead to believe that the key press is not registering properly, but I'm not sure where the error is. I've tried this on both Windows 10 and whatever the most recent Mac OS is.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* this is the same code as the 2nd example in the OP, just reformatted */

void keyPressed() {

  if (keyPressed) {
    if (key == CODED) {
      if (keyCode == UP) {
        x = x - 20;
        println("UP");
      } else if (keyCode == DOWN) {
        x = x + 20;
        println("DOWN");
      }
      if (keyPressed) {
        if (key == 'w') {
          x2 = x2 - 20;
          println(key);
        } else if (key == 's') {
          x2 = x2 + 20;
          println(key);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  println(x, x2);
}
```

The way your code implies it should work (based on the formatting in your post) vs. the actual formatting when you line up the parentheses is perhaps part of your problem.  You didn't post a complete reproducible example, so it's hard to understand if `key == CODED` needs to be true in all cases or not, but right now your horizontal movement is inside the outermost 2 `if` statements.  Is that intentional?

Comment: At the risk of sounding dense, I have to say that I'm not sure what the intention would or could be where the placement is concerned. 

Would it be helpful if I edited the post to include the entirety of the first program? My initial concern with doing that is that it would make the post too long and therefore unpleasant to read/address.

Comment: I also meant to ask, what I'd need to do in order to make the example complete enough to be reproducible?

Comment: Why do you check if keyPressed twice? Is the if else structure what you expect?

Comment: My initial assumption was that checking for coded keys would require a separate chain. I'll be adding an edit in a minute, but after considering your comment about placement and some playing around, my revised guess is that the chains do not need to be separate, but that the alphanumeric keyPressed checks have to come before the coded key checks. The movement still isn't exactly fluid, and it's far from perfect, but it technically works even if it's not an optimal solution.